# word timestamps in python pocketsphinx

Tags: python, speech, cmusphinx

I'm using pocketsphinx python bindings on ubuntu 11.10. I pass it a grammar and an audio file and it works perfectly. I am now looking to find the timestamp of each word in the audio file. I have seen:

```
void ps_seg_frames(ps_seg_t *seg, int *out_sf, int *out_ef);
```

which I believe should do what I need. 
However I can't seem to find away to do this in python.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is not implemented yet. There was a patch here but it was lost due to sourceforge outage it seems

https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=301904&aid=3480256&group_id=1904

It should be relatively easy to add this binding

Comment: How might one add this feature?

Comment: Hello. The patch to implement this feature has been just committed to subversion repository. Just download and compile the snapshot to have this functionality. See pocketsphinx/python/ps_test_seg.py for details on how to use it.

Comment: What exactly needs to be downloaded to use this functionality? I don't see this file on the cmusphinx repo (https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx), I only see it on a mirror (https://github.com/skerit/cmusphinx/blob/master/pocketsphinx/python/ps_test_seg.py)

Comment: This code is not relevant anymore in latest version